# Access SSRS report without entering login and password

Tags: angular, .net-core, reporting-services

In our .Net/Angular application we have some SSRS reports.
Well everything works fine but to see the reports, we need to enter the login and the password of the server like when opening the reports directly in the navigator.

Is there any solution so i can pass the login alert?
We just don't give the client a server password and facilate the use of the application so he doesn't need double authentication.

PS: We are using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Reportins Services

Any help and thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly (which I might not - been a while), by default SSRS is using NTLM for authentication and does not offer any kind of SSO out of the box. This means you will need to configure SSRS to use the custom authentication - which boils down to writing a custom ASP.NET Forms module that's used to authenticate the user.

See official [SQL Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/configure-custom-or-forms-authentication-on-the-report-server?view=sql-server-2017) for some additional details.

Word of advice (based on my VERY subjective experience) - if you have any saying in the matter - don't use SSRS. Go the extra mile and use PowerBI or other BI tool. It will make any kind of integration MUCH easier (flawless, even), will increase performance and the UX for end-users. Again, this is subjective - but do some additional research in the topic and think twice about it.

Comment: A client demanded the SSRS reports, anyway thanks for the respond I will try to work on the specific project.

Comment: can you help mere here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993019/using-a-specific-net-project-to-access-ssrs-raports-without-authentication  and Thanks